# PKUNZIP Commands

Tags: mainframe, jcl, mvs

Is it possible to unzip an archive with multiple files inside on mvs..

Currently we can unzip files using the PKUNZIP
command with this..

```
//UNZIP EXEC PKUNZIP
//SYSIN DD *
-ARCHIVE(TEST.FILE.ZIP)
-UNZIPPED_DSN(**,TEST.TEMP.DATA)
-TEXT
-OVERWITE
/*
```

this step only writes the last file from the zip and what we want is to get all the files from the zip.
is there another command for the overwite?

Comment: Hi there! I've not used PKUNZIP, but this person here seems to do it. Scroll down to the bottom and there's a couple of code snippets.

http://ibmmainframes.com/about46274.html

At the bottom, they use multiple UNZIPPED_DSN commands, one for each file they want to unzip.

Comment: Thanks works fine by specifying each file

Answer (score 0):

I've not used PKUNZIP, but [this person here](https://ibmmainframes.com/about46274.html) seems to do it. Scroll down to the bottom and there's a couple of code snippets.  At the bottom, they use multiple `UNZIPPED_DSN` commands, one for each file they want to unzip.

```
-UNZIPPED_DSN(HMS_Education.tab,TFRSS.HMS.EDUC.UNZIPPED)                
-UNZIPPED_DSN(HMS_Sanction.tab,TFRSS.HMS.SNCT.UNZIPPED)
```

Comment: hi i have another question, it seems like the reason i cant make it work is because i reached the Limit for the filename which is 54.. are there other options or configurations that can increase this?                                                 
-UNZIPPED_DSN(123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234.txt,TFRSS.HMS.EDUC.UNZIPPED)

Comment: So I'm not sure here but on reading the doc, it looks like UNZIPPED_DSN can be used more generically. 

  Example:
Given the archive: MDB/TYPE/RATE
and a command of: –UNZIPPED_DSN(MDB.TY,XXX.)
(note delimiter in newname)
the result will be: XXX.PE.RATE

  Example:
Given the archive: MDB/TYPE/RATE
and a command of: –UNZIPPED_DSN(*,XXX)
(note use of wildcard for high level qualifier in
oldname)
the result will be: XXX.TYPE.RATE

  Example:
Given the archive: MDB/TYPE/RATE
and a command of: –UNZIPPED_DSN(MDB.?YPE.,XXX)
(note delimiter in oldname)
the result will be: XXX.RATE

Comment: https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/manuals/PKMU-V5R5000.pdf page 138 sorry about the formatting